# Can I read a text file from another computer over internet with out using LAN/WAN/anything else?

Tags: java

I would like to rid out of this question with answer...
i am familiar with reading a local system file like as follows,

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   // ...
 }
```

assume that, i want to read a txtfile from my friend's computer he is online,and i am also online,so we can be connected only through internet(i dont use any other connections such as wan/lan etc..). my doubt is can i access my friend computer's txtfile through ip address or anything else using java programming...

pls help...

thnx in advance..

Comment: I'm perplexed: you want to use the Internet but not use a network? How do you connect the computers then?

Comment: Brain reading device. But I'm not sure that doesn't count as WAN... `only through internet(i dont use any other connections such as wan/lan` How do you use internet when not using WAN and LAN either?

Comment: it like asking you want to use your PC without a power cable\battery !!

Comment: Actually He misunderstood the words `LAN`, `WAN` and `Internet`. God bless him.

Comment: Why don't you guys help him? The problem is clear, he wants to access a file via internet and is not in a local network. A short note that the internet is a kind of WAN would have been enough.

Comment: @sotix 
> "i dont use any other connections such as wan/lan etc.."
made me(maybe rest also) understand that the CONNECTIONS DOES NOT EXISTS

Comment: @SrinathGanesh he also said "and i am also online" and "connected only through internet"

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

Map the location that has the file you want to access into a network drive and then use the code you have.

That means of course that you can map the location, (you have the persimissions, his IP, etc)

Option 2:

Install a java program on your friend PC that will create a socket server and serve the file over that socket. You need to create a program that will connect to this socket. Again of course you need permissions, the IP etc.

Check : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/ ofr a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

1. IP - Get the external IPs; easy; there are even sites giving you them.
2. Firewall - Allow access to your computer on some FTP port
3. FTP Server - Setup for FTP (File Transfer Protocol) serving files.
4. Use JSch or other Java libraries to communicate.

Teke care where you take your (S)FTP server from.